# Can not find Firebase crashlytics crash logs in react native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I am working on react native app and integrated firebase crashlytics in that. If I run app from  iOS folder using Xcode and crash the app its showing logs in firebase. But same if i run from visual code and crash the app the logs are not getting in firebase.

Is there anything i am missing which is causing this issue?

I am new to react native please let me know if more information needed to solve issue.

Thank You for help.

Comment: Did you follow this guide? https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/usage

Answer (score 0):

use sentry to check crash report in react-native

[image]